# vim How to not tabularize inside a string

Tags: vim, tabular

```
-- Some comments here
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMPS
 (
  CLICKS INT COMMENT 'Number of raw clicks for this impression.',
  VIEWS INT COMMENT 'Number of raw views for this impression'
 )
```

I want to tabularize the above to:

```
-- Some comments here
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMPS
 (
  CLICKS   INT   COMMENT   'Number of raw clicks for this impression.',
  VIEWS    INT   COMMENT   'Number of raw views for this impression'
 )
```

How can i do it? If i use `:Tab \` it is tabularizing inside of the string also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced with the tabular plugin, but from the documentation it looks like

```
:Tab / \@!<('.*)/
```

would work. The pattern matches a space character as long as there is no single quote before it on the line.

Comment: It wouldn't work with `CLICKS INT COMMENT 'Some text' OTHER THINGS` though. Perhaps there is a way to exclude not _if there is a single quote before it_, but _if there are an odd number of single quotes before it_?